# MiKTeX crashed on Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa)

Tags: miktex, ubuntu, miktex-update

I installed MikTeX from their official website on my Ubuntu 20.04 using shared settings and auto-installation. After opening the console for updates my system turned off due to a power failure and the next time I tried to open the MiKTeX console an error mentioning "File is empty" was displayed with details telling that ****.fndb-5 file is empty. As I wanted to use MiKTeX for writing article I was confused as what to do. If anyone finds a solution, kindly let me know.

Comment: Clearly it's supposed to work, but why miktex? Almost everyone using linux will be using texlive.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing an answer to this query in case anyone else has a similar problem in future. After reading similar posts I found out that going to the var/...../data/le folder I can find the ****.fndb-5 file mentioned in the error which can be removed and in case other errors pop-up with other ****.fndb-5 files they also can be removed until MiKTeX console starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

Only answering because of the "power failure" mention. I do not have Windows. But something similar happened to me with Linux. Apparently the system UUID and handshake is not foolproof. Solution is to remove then reinstall.